# Can't open file window

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, filemanager

I have this problem where sometimes when I click on the Files icon it shows a working icon but never opens a window. Once this starts happening it won't work unless I reboot the PC.

From `journalctl` I see this repeating:

```
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com dbus-daemon[3946]: [session uid=1000 pid=3946] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.1717' (uid=1000 pid=245020 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com org.freedesktop.FileManager1[260711]: Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com dbus-daemon[3946]: [session uid=1000 pid=3946] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.FileManager1 exited with status 1
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com gnome-shell[4126]: DING: Error creating proxy, "Nautilus" is needed for Desktop Icons: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.FileManager1: Process org.freedesktop.FileManager1 exited with status 1
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com gnome-shell[4126]: DING: _injectToMethod/klass[method]@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:273:25
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com gnome-shell[4126]: DING: _makeProxyWrapper/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:250:17
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com gnome-shell[4126]: DING: makeNewProxy@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/dbusUtils.js:128:85
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com gnome-shell[4126]: DING: ProxyManager/<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/dbusUtils.js:86:26
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com gnome-shell[4126]: DING: _emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/_signals.js:114:47
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com gnome-shell[4126]: DING: _emitChangedSignal/this._signalTimerID<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/dbusUtils.js:274:22
Mar 14 06:06:49 vbpw68-x01.ds.mot.com gnome-shell[4126]: DING: @/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/ding.js:159:9
```